# Is there a standard reference designator to use for labelling indicator lamps in schematics?

Tags: schematics, standard

In a schematic, LEDs typically are labelled using the letter 'D' since they are diodes.  From what I can tell, it seems that there is no standard for labelling indicator lamps (e.g. small incandescent bulbs) in a schematic.  My question is: is there a letter that is typically used for labelling indicator lamps in schematics?  Or is there any published standard which defines the "proper" labels to use in schematics for indicator lamps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact there is a standard: IEEE Std315-1975 *Graphic Symbols for Electrical and
Electronics Diagrams (Including Reference Designation Letters)*

The standard specifies a reference designator of "DS" for a "general light source", "lamp", and "signal light". It has the same reference designation for "light-emitting solid-state device", by the way.

Comment: Thanks!  I was aware of 315-1975, but unfortunately don't have a copy, and am not too inclined to shell out the cash for one.  In searching the internet for indicator lamps in schematics, however, most had no reference designator, and a few used "L", which would be a problem if you also have inductors in your schematic.